# System of first order differential equation objective question.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations, skew-symmetric-matrices

Let $A\in M_3(\mathbb R)$ be a skew-symmetric matrix and $x:[0,\infty)\to\mathbb R^3$ be a solution of $$x’(t)=Ax(t),\forall t\in (0,\infty)$$ Which of the following statements are true?

$1.$ $\|x(t)\|=\|x(0)\|,\forall t\in(0,\infty).$

$2.$ for some $a\in\mathbb R^3-\{0\},  \|x(t)-a\|=\|x(0)-s\|,\forall t\in(0,\infty).$

$3.$ $x(t)-x(0)\in img(A),\forall t\in(0,\infty)$.

$4.$ $\lim_{t\to\infty}x(t)$ exists.

I am trying to solve this problem . I can see last option is wrong as because of term $cos(at)$ and $ sin(at)$  in solution, so limit does not exist for non-zero matrix  as $t\to\infty$. I am unable to handle first three options. If eigen values of skew symmetric matrix $A$ are $0,\pm ai$ and corresponding Eigne vectors are $V_1,V_2$ and $V_3$, then solution is given by $x(t)=V_1+e^{ait}V_2+e^{-ait}V_3$. $x(0)=V_1+V_2+V_3$, how $\|x(t)\|=\|x(0)\|?$ How to solve first three options. Please help. Thank you.

Comment: To answer 1 and 2, you need the orthogonality of the eigenvectors; the eigenvalues alone do not tell you enough. 3 is quite simple if you think about it, especially if you know something about numerical methods. 4 as you say is generically false, but in general it depends on where you start.

Comment: This is obviously an exercise, so I will only give some hints. 1. Define $V(t)=x(t)^Tx(t)$, then analyze how this evolves over time. 2. Same thing but with $V_a(t)=(x(t)-a)^T(x(t)-a)$. 3. What is the explicit solution for $x(t)$?  4. This will depend on the initial condition.

Comment: @lan if you solve only first option then rest I will do . Thank you.

Comment: @neelkanth We are not going to solve that for you.